# ie8 playing funny with list-style-position: inside

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Ok,

So problem here... when using list-style-position:inside in IE8 the first like is indented but every line after that is not. So the new lines appear under the bullet.

This is fine, but when I use a list with that css applied with an a tag within the li then the text automatically gets pushed to the second line, and the first line is empty.

[ie8 bug http://www.rocketspark.co.nz/bug_images/ie8_list.png](http://www.rocketspark.co.nz/bug_images/ie8_list.png)

When I remove the a tag from the li then it jumps back up.

Any idea on why this might be or is this a bug in the ie8 world or do I just need to double check my css?

Any insights would be much appreciated.

As asked here is some code

```
<div id="sub_nav">
<ul>
...    
<li><a class="active_page" href="#">Liposculpture</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">What is Liposculpture?</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Liposculpture surgery</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="active_sub">After Liposculpture surgery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Op Instructions</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Liposculpture Side Effects</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Liposuction Introduction to</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tumescent Liposculpture</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

For the CSS I will try and show it best I can

```
#sub_nav li {
    width: 200px;
    padding:4px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}

#sub_nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#555;
    padding:7px 15px 7px 15px;
    display: block;
}

#sub_nav li ul li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    font: 11px Arial;
    padding-left:15px;
    color:#FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#sub_nav li ul li a {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Mmmm... it looks like IE8 is having problems when calculating the width of the "a" (displayed as block) and pushing it down to a new line.  The first thing I would try would be adding a width to the "a" element, to see if that's the problem. Is there any URL to see the problem ( ok, I could create one with your code, but I'm feeling lazy ;D )

Comment: It seems you were indeed correct! I can't believe I didn't pick up on this earlier. It was indeed the display block that was affecting it. I change the width and that it make the "a" smaller but didn't fix the problem. So I just set the display:inline (must of inherited block). Thanks for that!

Comment: @salgiza Had the same problem and your answer helped. Thank you. You should consider providing a real answer bellow instead of a comment so that the OP could accept it.

Comment: Try whit this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working

Answer (score 3):

change

```
#sub_nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#555;
    padding:7px 15px 7px 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
#sub_nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#555;
    padding:7px 15px 7px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@salgiza posted the answer in the comments above... "it looks like IE8 is having problems when calculating the width of the "a" (displayed as block) and pushing it down to a new line. The first thing I would try would be adding a width to the "a" element, to see if that's the problem."