# IE list-style-position:inside issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hi I'm having issues with `list-style-position: inside` when using IE. On Firefox or Chrome it does not seem to have this problem.

```css
ol.myList { list-style-position:inside; }
ol.myList li { padding:20px 10px; font-weight:bold }
ol.myList li p { font-weight:normal }
```

```html
<ol class="myList" start="1">
    <li>
        <h4>My Title</h4>
        <p>My Details</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

On Chrome/Firefox it shows like this:

```
1. My Title
My Details
```

But on IE it shows this:

```
1.
My Title
My Details
```

Any suggestion in order to get it to work on IE?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799874/ie8-playing-funny-with-list-style-position-inside)?

Comment: Fix your faulty HTML first – `ol` can only have `li` as children, the `br` have no place being there. And why do you put a `br` as first element into the `li`, if you don’t want a line break there …?

Comment: @CBroe Hi I fixed the HTML already, which is supposedly to be shown as above now. As just now when I copied and paste my code into the textbox just now it didn't accept under the coding blocks and directly interpret it to HTML and not showing the HTML codes instead.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Hi, I tried adding to **display:inline-block;display:inline;zoom:1;** apparently the number went missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an inconsistency among browsers. Firefox displays the number/bullet on a separate line, as does IE.

Use `display: inline-block` on the `h4` and `*display: inline; zoom: 1;` for IE7.

```
ol.myList li h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Quote from the Mozilla documentation regarding this issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position#Browser_compatibility

> N.B. There is variance among browsers regarding behaviour when a block
>   element is placed first within a list element declared as
>   list-style-position:inside. Chrome and Safari both place this element
>   on the same line as the marker box, whereas Firefox, Internet Explorer
>   and Opera place it on the next line. For more information on this, see
>   this Mozilla [Bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36854) and an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hydrurga/MAS7j/).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. Was pulling my hair out wondering what was wrong with it. Really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ah Pek, try this:

```
ol.myList li h4 { display: inline-block; }
```

or

```
ol.myList li h4 { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Hi Leann.  Thanks for helping out.  Really appreciate it!